# SharedPreferences gives default values on some devices

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am using this code to save key-value pair in shared preferences and its working fine on my device but on emulators and other real devices, it always returns the default values.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

public static final String USER_PREFS = "com.aamir.friendlocator.friendlocator.USER_PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

private static String userKey="";

GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;

static final int PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
boolean FINE_LOCATION_PERMISSION_GRANTED = false;



TextView textViewLocationData;
TextView textViewKeyDisplay;
Button buttonRefresh;
Button btnCopyKey;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            goToActivityFriends();
        }
    });
    fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_people_white_48dp));
    textViewLocationData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLocationData);
     textViewKeyDisplay =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvKeyDisplay);
    buttonRefresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRefresh);
    btnCopyKey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCopyKey);
    sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(USER_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String key = sharedPreferences.getString("key", "");
    if(!key.equals("")) {
        textViewKeyDisplay.setText(key);
    }
    // Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
    buildGoogleApiClient();

    //user_sp = getSharedPreferences(USER_PREFS, 0);

    buttonRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            displayLocation();
        }
    });

    btnCopyKey.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("userKey", textViewKeyDisplay.getText().toString());
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Key copied !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
}

private void displayLocation() {

    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if ( permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

        textViewLocationData.setText(latitude + ", " + longitude);
        sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(USER_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String key = sharedPreferences.getString("key", "");
        Log.d("User Key",key);
        updateServers(latitude, longitude,key);

    } else {
        textViewLocationData
                .setText("Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device");
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                FINE_LOCATION_PERMISSION_GRANTED = true;
                //displayLocation();
            } else {
                FINE_LOCATION_PERMISSION_GRANTED = false;
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.i("", "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
            + result.getErrorCode());
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

    // Once connected with google api, get the location
    //displayLocation();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

public void goToActivityFriends () {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.aamir.friendlocator.friendlocator.Friends.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void updateServers(Double lat,Double lon,String Key) {
    if (Key.equals("")) {
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
        SendLocation cleint = retrofit.create(SendLocation.class);

        Call<com.aamir.friendlocator.friendlocator.Models.SendLocation> call = cleint.registerUser(String.valueOf(lat), String.valueOf(lon), Key);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<com.aamir.friendlocator.friendlocator.Models.SendLocation>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<com.aamir.friendlocator.friendlocator.Models.SendLocation> call, Response<com.aamir.friendlocator.friendlocator.Models.SendLocation> response) {
                Log.d("Response", response.body().getUserKey());
                if (!response.body().getUserKey().isEmpty()) {

                    String key_user = response.body().getUserKey();
                    textViewKeyDisplay.setText(key_user);

                    // Writing data to SharedPreferences
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("key", userKey);
                    if(editor.commit()){
                        Log.d("saved","saved");
                    }



                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<com.aamir.friendlocator.friendlocator.Models.SendLocation> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Response", t.toString());
            }
        });


    }
    else {
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://demoanalysis.com/pro03/FriendLocator/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
        SendLocation cleint = retrofit.create(SendLocation.class);

        Call<com.aamir.friendlocator.friendlocator.Models.SendLocation> call = cleint.updateLocation(String.valueOf(lat), String.valueOf(lon), Key);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<com.aamir.friendlocator.friendlocator.Models.SendLocation>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<com.aamir.friendlocator.friendlocator.Models.SendLocation> call, Response<com.aamir.friendlocator.friendlocator.Models.SendLocation> response) {
                Log.d("Response", response.body().getLocationStatus());
                if (!response.body().getLocationStatus().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response.body().getLocationStatus(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<com.aamir.friendlocator.friendlocator.Models.SendLocation> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Response", t.toString());
            }
        });

    }


}
```

}

On some devices, it's working perfectly. I did change context from this to getApplicationContext but no progress. I have updated the code.

Comment: Try it with the `editor. commit();` I am also facing same issue.

Comment: If my answer helps you then please mark as a right my answer from tick mark ad upvote pls otherwise i'm gonna remove this answer brother : https://www.google.com/search?q=right+mark+as+an+answer+stackoverflow&sxsrf=ACYBGNQVsfXj9VeT9WRKWerxeSRoAMe2uQ:1579936139192&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQk-DimJ7nAhWBc30KHdm9CGAQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1517&bih=730#imgrc=9_JN49MpzDykBM:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

**tl;dr** : you write the wrong variable into the preferences.

Your variable `userKey` is never written and always an empty string.
In your retrofit `onResponse` you put `userKey` as value of "key" into the
preferences. This writes an empty string into the preferences. This will work and give you no error.

Please assign `userKey` with the value of `key_user`.
Your response is only stored to `key_user`.

*Or directly remove the local variable key_user as follows:*

```
public void onResponse(Call<com.aamir.friendlocator.friendlocator.Models.SendLocation> call, Response<com.aamir.friendlocator.friendlocator.Models.SendLocation> response) {
                Log.d("Response", response.body().getUserKey());
                if (!response.body().getUserKey().isEmpty()) {

                    String userKey = response.body().getUserKey();
                    textViewKeyDisplay.setText(userKey);

                    // Writing data to SharedPreferences
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("key", userKey);
                    if(editor.commit()){
                        Log.d("saved","saved");
                    }
                }  
            }
```

---

**Before:**

In your code to save, you directly try to gather the previously saved value using `editor.apply();`

As documentation states out, `apply` will save your changes in background on a different thread.

Therefore your changes might not be saved at the time you try to get the value, 
some lines below.

Try to use `editor.commit();` instead and check if the problem is still there.

Comment: As @JacksOnF1re said, `apply` will save the changes in another thread. If you retrieve the values right after you apply them, it is indeed possible that the behavior will differ from a scenario to another (even on the same device). You should either use `commit` or [listen for the changes applied](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener)

Comment: Well I tried commit and its not working. And even commit return true but even though default value is printing.

Comment: Then you have some other issues with your code, because `commit` works atomically, as stated by the Javadoc.

Comment: I doubt that you have the problem in your running code, but..where did you initialize your first instance of sharedPreferences? Is this the full code? The code as it is, should throw an NPE.

Comment: No this is not full code. I initialize shared preferences in onCreate and use it in some methods or inside Retrofit class.

Comment: Please add at least the line where you initialize your preferences, of which you get your editor from. SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ....;

Comment: I did try commit but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm share here my own Preference Class it's too easy so you can put in any project.

Put this class into your util folder or anywhere.

**AppPreference.java**

```
package util;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

/**
 * Created by Pranav on 25/06/16.
 */
public class AppPreference {

    public static final String PREF_IS_LOGIN = "prefIsLogin";

        public static final class PREF_KEY {
        public static final String LOGIN_STATUS = "loginstatus";
    }

    public static final void setStringPref(Context context, String prefKey, String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(prefKey, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
        edit.putString(key, value);
        edit.commit();
    }

    public static final String getStringPref(Context context, String prefName, String key) {
        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(prefName, 0);
        return sp.getString(key, "");
    }
```

}

Set Preference Value in Login.java when user Login set value like this :

```
 AppPreference.setStringPref(context, AppPreference.PREF_IS_LOGIN, AppPreference.PREF_KEY.LOGIN_STATUS, "0");
```

Then you will get Login Status Value in any Class by Calling like this :

```
 String LoginStatus = AppPreference.getStringPref(context, AppPreference.PREF_IS_LOGIN, AppPreference.PREF_KEY.LOGIN_STATUS);
```

Comment: Why should I reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I did not got you what do you mean? how can i help to you? @Wijdan

Comment: I am saying Why should not I use shared preferences and create a whole new similar feature if I can debug and get it working.